# error al subir el sitio por FilleZilla

Tags: html

Suponemos que al subir el sitio web por Filezilla, al dar clic a nuestro URL debería aparecer nuestro sitio web, solo se suben los archivos, pero no aparece la página.

[image: este es mi error]

Comment: Tu pagina principal se debe llamar `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

si es tu archivo "C.html" es tu página entonces: debes renombrarlo a "index.html".
 
**Explicación**:
"La página index.html es el nombre más común utilizado para la página predeterminada que se muestra en un sitio web si no se especifica ninguna otra página cuando un visitante solicita el sitio. En otras palabras, index.html es el nombre utilizado para la página de inicio del sitio web."

Comment: La razón del nombre index es por que apache o nginx tienen configurado buscar archivos con este nombre para mostrar

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo.